# JSON string sending in multiple messages. discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently making a Discord bot. The code I've provided below is supposed to get data from Hypixel to display guild info. It's getting the correct info, but I want to send all the names as one message instead of one person per message.

This is my code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
 name: 'hguild',
 aliases: ['hg'],
 description: 'Shows info about a hypixel guild!',
 guildOnly: true,
 args: true,
 usage: '<player>',
 execute(message, args) {
  var ruuid = [];

  const guildName = args[0];
  message.channel.send('Please wait, checking API').then((msg) => {
   fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=[REMOVED]&name=${guildName}`)
    .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
    .then((json) => {
     console.log(json);

     msg.edit('Here is about your guild!');

     for (const guild of json.guild.members) {
      const rawUsername = guild.uuid;

      fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/${rawUsername}/names`)
       .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
       .then((json) => {
        console.log(json[0].name);
        if (json.name == null || json.status == 'ERR') {
        }
        var testList = [json[0].name];
        message.channel.send(testList);
       });
     }
    });
  });
 },
};
```

Currently its showing all the names, but sends one name per message. I want to group all these names together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of executing these two lines:

```js
var testList = [json[0].name];
message.channel.send(testList);
```

And *then* closing the `for` loop, try pushing the results to an array initialized *before* the loop, then send that. Example:

```js
var testList = [];
const getUsernames = async () => {
 for await (const guild of json.guild.members) {
  const rawUsername = guild.uuid;

  fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/${rawUsername}/names`)
   .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .catch((err) => message.channel.send(err))
   .then((json) => {
    console.log(json[0].name);
    if (json.name == null || json.status == 'ERR') {
    }
    testList.push(json[0].name);
   });
 }
};
await getUsernames();
message.channel.send(testList.join('\n'));
```

Make sure you change the `execute(message, args)` line at the top of your code to `async execute(message, args)` so that `await` is possible.

---

As a disclaimer, I am not knowledgable in the Minecraft API area, and do not know how the object returned from your request is structured. This is just my best guess.

Comment: That would be because the `for` loop isn't going fast enough, so the `message.channel.send` function in executing before anything is being pushed to the array. I'll edit my answer momentarily to account for this.

Comment: ^ For context, that was in response to a comment that is now deleted

Answer (score 0):

@Lioness100 Also unfamiliar with the Minecraft API.

I'm curious about the loop, seems like your initial fetch to the api with guild info returns what you're looking for.

Are you deconstructing names to test the functionality to eventually push entire profiles to discord? or are you content with just names?

(For the latter, instead of the loop have you tried)

```
message.channel.send(json.guild.members)
```

Otherwise another thing to consider would be utilizing the loop to generate an array of URLs that you could resolve together with a `Promise.all.` Wondering if the undesired output is a result of asynchronous behavior. Here's the api docs for reference:

```
https://javascript.info/promise-api
```

Hope that works, friend!